# Referring to a two dimensional array - rows and columns

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, loops, multidimensional-array, matrix

*I have a two dimensional array and I want to know how I can refer to the rows and columns in it. Do I use [row,column] or [column,row]? I also have some graphics. Do I calculate the (x,y) coordinate set of each graphic with (row*size,col*size) or with (col*size,row*size)?*

The whole two dimensional array is the building instructions for the grid.
Each element in the array refers to a piece of the grid.
I know how to construct this grid and its pieces and I know how to access and manipulate the array's elements.

The problem is that when I construct the grid I have to calculate the x and y coordinate of each piece, but I just don't know if my variable curRow should be used for the x or y coordinate. It's similarly with the variable curCol.

My code is working, but it confuses me.
I think of it like the rows control the y coordinates and the columns control the x coordinates, because I just learned of the way matrices are referred to.
I ask, because it came to my mind that I am unsure of how to do this.
In the past I have used [row,column] to loop and (row*size,col*size) to position.

The code so far is:

```
function buildGrid(gridInfo:Array):Sprite {
    var displaySprite:Sprite = new Sprite();

    for(var curRow:uint=0;curRow<gridInfo.length;curRow++) {
        for(var curCol:uint=0;curCol<gridInfo[curRow].length;curCol++) {
            var infoRef:Object = gridInfo[curRow][curCol];//create reference for fast access

            var pieceGraphic:Shape = new Shape();
            pieceGraphic.graphics.beginFill(infoRef.fillColor);
            pieceGraphic.graphics.lineStyle(infoRef.borderThickness,infoRef.theBorderColor);
            pieceGraphic.graphics.drawRect(0,0,infoRef.sideLength,infoRef.sideLength);
            pieceGraphic.graphics.endFill();

            pieceGraphic.x = curRow*(infoRef.sideLength+infoRef.spaceX);//later use of graphic requires known x
            pieceGraphic.y = curCol*(infoRef.sideLength+infoRef.spaceY);//later use of graphic requires known y

            displaySprite.addChild(pieceGraphic);
        }
    }

    return displaySprite;
}
```

Comment: Just use x and y and think of it in terms of the grid - x is width, y is height.  rows and columns is an arbitrary name for the arrays.  Making this curX and curY relates more clearly for me.  But your code is fine, so try drawing it on a sheet of paper and you might grasp it a little better.

Comment: Great idea of calling it curX and curY. It makes perfect sense to me. I know that there isn't rows and columns to multidimensional arrays so the alternative variable names are great. It still seems like the matrices uses rows and columns differently, but I havn't had about matrices in math class yet so I will just ignore it for now.

Comment: I get another problem when I don't create gridInfo the programmatic way (for rows, for columns). The buildGrid() creates a sprite for my TD game. I manually create a gridInfo for most of the maps. I draw maps on paper and write what I see in an array, but how many rows and columns are there on the map? I have to flip the array, because I don't see what should be in the array! If I make a 12 by 22 tiles map I see 12 rows by 22 columns.. I will solve the problem by taking an extra parameter and calling my function rotateMatrix() if it's a manually created map. I write the function later.

Comment: That rotateMatrix() function.. I think rotating the paper is easier!
I have only created one map manually so it isn't much extra work. I will say that this question has an answer.

Comment: Well, I believe you can choose either "array of rows" or "array of columns" for your grid, but you have to be consistent of what indexes mean throughout your project. About drawing - "array of columns" is intuitively easier, as you have X horizontally and Y vertically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's correct to refer to a two dimensional array with [row,column], but it's easier with other variable names like curX and curY. It's important to be consistent of what the indexes mean throughout the project and what indexes are used. To access the first elements in the array create a loop for rows or for curX and for the elements in the second dimension create a loop for columns or for curY.

You can calculate coordinate sets (x,y) for graphics in a grid with (row*size,col*size) or (curX*size,curY*size), so your code is correct and doesn't need to be changed.

Remember that rows are horizontal and columns are vertical.